Solve for $x$: $\lfloor 2^x\rfloor+\lfloor 3^x\rfloor=\lfloor 6^x\rfloor$
Solve for $x$: $\lfloor 2^x\rfloor+\lfloor 3^x\rfloor=\lfloor 6^x\rfloor$
My Attempt:
Clearly the equation is satisfied for all $x<0$.
For positive $x$,
$2^x+3^x-6^x=\{2^x\}+\{3^x\}-\{6^x\}$
$-1<\{2^x\}+\{3^x\}-\{6^x\}<2$
where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$
After this I am not able to conclude anything

There is no solution for $x\ge 1$, because adding $3\cdot6^{\left(x-1\right)}\ge 2^{x}+1$ and $3\cdot6^{\left(x-1\right)}\ge 3^{x}$ results in $$6^{x}\ge 2^{x}+3^{x}+1 > 2^x + 3^x$$Therefore the rest of the solutions are in $x \in (0,1)$

This can be solved by writing each summand as a table for values of $x\in(0,1)$. You will end up with the union of two intervals after it's all said and done.

Another way to see there are no solutions when $x\geq 1$: take the negative of the first equation you wrote, add 1, and you can factor to get $(2^x-1)(3^x-1)={6^x}-{2^x}-{3^x}+1<2$, but the left hand side is the product of two positive increasing functions when $x>0$, and evaluating at $x=1$ yields $(2-1)(3-1)=2$.

Extending my comment as a solution, for $x\in(0,1)$, $\lfloor 2^x \rfloor = 1$, $\lfloor 3^x \rfloor = \begin{cases}1, x < \log_3(2)\\ 2, x\ge \log_3(2)   \end{cases}$ and $$\lfloor 6^x \rfloor = \begin{cases}1, x < \log_6(2)\\ 2, \log_6(2) \le x< \log_6(3) \\ 3, \log_6(3) \le x< \log_6(4) \\  4, \log_6(4) \le x< \log_6(5) \\ 5, \log_6(5) \le x< 1 \end{cases}.$$ Therefore, the left side is either $2$ for $x<\log_2(3)$ or $3$ for $x\ge \log_2(3)$. Thus the solution is $$(\log_{6}\left(2\right),\log_{6}\left(3\right)) \cup (\log_{3}\left(2\right),\log_{6}\left(4\right))$$
Edit : From the inequality $6^x \ge 2^x+3^x+1$, we can take floor$()$ both sides as it an increasing function. Now since $\lfloor x+y \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor y \rfloor$ or $\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor y \rfloor+1$, we get $$\lfloor 6^x \rfloor \ge \lfloor  2^x \rfloor+\lfloor 3^x \rfloor +1 > \lfloor  2^x \rfloor+\lfloor 3^x \rfloor.$$
